# How to add one more \ next to \

Tags: python

My input is `folder_src = 'D:\TEST\BOE\7-13-2'` , I want to add another \ next to \ as `folder_src = 'D:\\TEST\\BOE\\7-13-2'`.
How will I be able to do it?

Comment: Just put `\\\`s together

Comment: I want to skip that process

Comment: Side note: the process doesn't seem to make sense if this is a file path: the directory separators are single backslashes in Windows, not double. Any reason why you want to do this?

Comment: When converting files through jupyterlab, i need to insert a file address, but it is cumbersome to enter additional \ every time.

Comment: @rermk: In case the path is hard coded in the script, you could use forward slashes as well: `folder_src = 'D:/TEST/BOE/7-13-2'`

Comment: As I understand you have a problem with the path itself, why not try `folder_src = r'D:\TEST\BOE\7-13-2'`

Answer (score 1):

Use `replace`:

```py
folder_src = 'D:\\TEST\\BOE\\7-13-2'
output = folder_src.replace('\\', '\\\\')
print(output)  # D:\\TEST\\BOE\\7-13-2
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to use your windows path is with [raw string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals) like this:

`folder_src = r'D:\TEST\BOE\7-13-2'`

With this the string will be sent exactly as it is written and you wouldn't need the `\\`.